# Rancher pull image from local machine (not local/remote registry)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, rancher

I have rancher running on Machine A. I want rancher to deploy a dojo image on Machine B where the image is already on the machine but not on a private/local/remote registry. If I try to get rancher to pull the image, it'll say the image can't be found but if I set up a private/local/remote registry on Machine B, rancher is able to pull it. Can someone explain why this is the case? I'm very new rancher but I had thought that Rancher essentially also resides on Machine B and can execute commands like a normal user can.

Here is my docker-compose file that I'm using

```
version: '2'
services:
  js-engine:
  image: dojo
  ports:
    - "15555:8443"
  volumes:
    - /etc/certs:/etc/certs
    - /etc/pki/java/cacerts:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security
  labels:
    io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: bench=bundle-services
```

This is on Rancher 1.X.X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the registry credentials in Rancher.

See screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I had to do that to get it to work with the local registry. I'm wondering if this will work if I don't deploy a local registry. The registry that's accessible when you enter in "docker image ls"

Comment: Let's say you have an image `someregistry:5000/annihil8ted/myapp:v1.0` present on machine B but it's not pushed to someregistry:5000, the container should be able to start on machine B.

Comment: It was exactly as you said. The issue turned out to be a selinux problem not allowing docker to pull locally. Changing that in the docker start up options solved that.

Comment: Also if your Container Engine in Rancher Desktop is set to `containerd` then your commands for containers and images should be `nerdctl` not `docker`.